# Android Jsoup parser with input value

Tags: android, jsoup

I Need Get url as a string from this code. Only i need 
   (http://ww3.mp3juices.com/download/5487/8789094/123735064/1d8bb8aa0352/(osthi)---kalasala-kalasala )

```
<td style="width:240px;min-width:240px" class="controls">
    <a class="action_buttons cs download" href="http://yournewncsoft.info/v356?product_name=%28Osthi%29+-+Kalasala+Kalasala&product_title=MP3Juices+Download+Manager&installer_file_name=%28Osthi%29+-+Kalasala+Kalasala+-+%5BMP3Juices.com%5D&product_file_name=%28Osthi%29+-+Kalasala+Kalasala+-+%5BMP3Juices.com%5D.mp3&product_download_url=http%3A%2F%2Fww3.mp3juices.com%2Fdownload%2F5487%2F8789094%2F123735064%2F1d8bb8aa0352%2F%28osthi%29---kalasala-kalasala" name="dl2" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/download/manager']);">ev
    <input type="hidden" name="files[1][adrl]" value="http://yournewncsoft.info/v356?product_name=%28Osthi%29+-+Kalasala+Kalasala&product_title=MP3Juices+Download+Manager&installer_file_name=%28Osthi%29+-+Kalasala+Kalasala+-+%5BMP3Juices.com%5D&product_file_name=%28Osthi%29+-+Kalasala+Kalasala+-+%5BMP3Juices.com%5D.mp3&product_download_url=http%3A%2F%2Fww3.mp3juices.com%2Fdownload%2F5487%2F8789094%2F123735064%2F1d8bb8aa0352%2F%28osthi%29---kalasala-kalasala"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="files[1][url]" value="http://ww3.mp3juices.com/download/5487/8789094/123735064/1d8bb8aa0352/(osthi)---kalasala-kalasala"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="files[1][len]" value="252"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="files[1][song_id]" value="2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="files[1][hash]" value="41e78609200a6de8d86d25bae2b2a922"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="files[1][filesize]" value="480.99999999999994"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="files[1][bitrate]" value="160"/>
    <a class="action_buttons cs listen" href="javascript:;" name="dll2">ev
</td>
```

My Jsoup Code is

```
for (Element divAudio : divs){
    count_songs++;
    String songTitle = divAudio.select(".song_title").text();
    //String songURL = divAudio.select(".url").attr("href");
    Element link = divAudio.select("input[name=files[1][url]]").first();
    String songURL= link.attr("value");
    String songDuration = divAudio.select(".size").text();
    String songSize = divAudio.select(".bit").text();
    result_list.add(new song_details(songTitle, songURL, songDuration, songSize));
}
```

Edited: ANSWER IS:

```
Element link = divAudio.select("input[name*=url").first();
            String songURL= link.attr("value");
```

Comment: The HTML code seems incomplete for the Java code you've mentioned.  What is the code referred to by divs?  The <td> tag?

Comment: Assuming you have the displayed <td> tag in a JSoup `Document doc`, this `doc.select("td").get(0).select("input[name*=url").attr("value")` should get you the URL.

Comment: If your answer is solved, please post your solution as an answer and accept it ( see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Element link = divAudio.select("input[name*=url").first();
        String songURL= link.attr("value");
```

This code working fine